# Fetching data from a slider to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch time from slider user input to set a pulse time for a port but my function shows "null" value while running.

I am using a form in order to submit the user input time this is linked with port 1 so when the port 1 is turned on it will run till the time set with the slider
.
JavaScript:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("pulse_time_1");
    var output = document.getElementById("P1_PT");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function Port1_pulsetime(){
        if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("pulse_time_1").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }
            else {
                console.log("not connected")
            }
        return false;   
    }
```

html code:

```
<tr height=40>
        <td><style="text-align:middle">PORT1</td>
        <td width=40></td>
        <td><label id="sw1", class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span> 
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr height=40>
        <td><style="text-align:middle">PORT1 PULSE TIME</td>
        <td width=40></td>
        <form id="P1_pulsetime" onsubmit="">
        <div class="slidercontainer">
        <input type="range" min="10" max="120" value="20" class="slider" id="pulse_time_1">
        <p>Time:<span id="P1_PT"></span></p>
        </div>
        </td>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="Port1_pulsetime" value="P1_pulsetime">
        </form>
    </tr>
```

error shown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null    at file:///C:/Users/Apple/Downloads/Trial_success%2020_6_18%20mandeep%20(1).html:322:28
```

[here is the image of output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQOw8.png)

Comment: Where does it become null exactly? What exact variable? If it's inside the function, and it's connected to the `var slider` and `var output`, it's because the function works within it's own scope, and those variables are outside of that scope. Either parse them as parameters, or fetch the values inside the function. More on function scopes here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: on html page where I run it shows null error, I have tried both the ways it shows the same error.

Comment: Do you know what "exactly" becomes null? Like what value? Something has to "be" null. Can you copy paste the exact error in your question as well? (ctrl+shift+i > console in Chrome).

Comment: yes,error is in this statement: message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("pulse_time_1").value);

Comment: I found the root to your variable error. However, now I get an error with your function coming up as not defined. I'll need a minute or 2.

Comment: What exactly is "connected_flag" ? it's not defined anywhere and breaks your function. Once that is resoved, I have everything working. Also, `slider.oninput = function Port1_pulsetime(){` seems to be some incorrect syntax. You should add the function manually "oninput" directly to the element.

Comment: Also, are you using some sort of javascript library? Some of your functions don't work for me. Like `client.whatever`, `paho.blabla` etc.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is unable to read the value of something that you created. Debug your code and make sure that your values are existed in your document.

```
var temp,
pulseTime = document.getElementById("pulse_time_1");
if (pulseTime != null) {
    temp= pulseTime.value;
}
else {
    temp = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is correct. Mainly these sections, which don't work to me, but might for you?

`if(connected_flag==1){` - *connected_flag* is *NOT* defined anywhere, so either you are missing something, overlooked something, or provided incomplete code.

`client.subscribe("lazy/test");` - *client* is not a native JavaScript function. Are you using a library?

`Paho.MQTT.Message()` - This is not native JavaScript either. Again, use of library?

`message.destinationName` - *message* is not a native JavaScript function.

`client.send()` - again, *client* is not a native JavaScript function.

However, if I assume that all of those are functions that is available to you, and that they do not infact cause any issues, and that you are able to do your condition, despite *connected_flag* not being defined in your question, the following should work:

```
<table>
    <tr height=40>
        <td><style="text-align:middle">PORT1 PULSE TIME</td>
        <td width=40></td>
        <form id="P1_pulsetime" onsubmit="">
            <div class="slidercontainer">
                <input type="range" min="10" max="120" value="20" class="slider" id="pulse_time_1" oninput="Port1_pulsetime();">
                <p>Time:<span id="P1_PT"></span></p>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="Port1_pulsetime();" value="P1_pulsetime">
        </form>
    </tr>

    <tr height=40>
        <td><style="text-align:middle">PORT2</td>
        <td width=40></td>
        <td><label id="sw2", class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider"></span> 
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>    
    var slider = document.getElementById("pulse_time_1").value;
    console.log(slider);
    var output = document.getElementById("P1_PT");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    function Port1_pulsetime(){
        if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("PULSE 1" + document.getElementById("pulse_time_1").value);
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }
            else {
                console.log("not connected")
            }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Your problem was that JavaScript, like the HTML, is read top-down by the browser's compiler, so I just moved it around a bit. The value is now retrieved correctly at least, which was the problem described in your question. I also added the oninput directly to your element, which is the proper syntax.

Comment: hey,I made the changes as suggested by you but still the code doesn't seem to follow the range also the error is still present I am adding few images have a look...and I have already uploaded edited code.

Comment: You should not be getting any null values if you structured your code *exactly* like I did.

Comment: Here's the test sample: https://gyazo.com/11f06e22c59ed43a4d9de43bcf52a7fc you can see in the console log that it finds the value "20" just fine.

Comment: yes its work similar way, but the issue is the range which I have set is 10-120 but the range while running the code starts from 110.

Comment: It starts at 20 for me, because that's the set value. At least going from the code I have, and *nothing* else. As you can see here https://gyazo.com/123950e3a6e968dd42848156b5d0c050 you see that the slider's indicator is at the spot that would look like 20, as well as the console output that indeed tells you that it's 20.